Gnome log issues
I am using a laptop with Ubuntu 24.04 as the only OS. I have upgraded the OS on this laptop incrementally since 17.04. The laptop is running perfectly under 24.04 but I get the following "Important" errors in the Gnome logs after startup. What do they mean?

Just an FYI for you cut and paste that into the question and it can be read without having to open another screen to see it, it is super small text.

@David DE I haven't figured out how to copy the output of the Gnome log. How do you do it? The usual mouse and keyboard methods don't work!
